# QTableWidget.setCellWidget creates windows of the given widget while using multi threading

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, pyqt5

So this code loads all the data from database and puts it in my table and works perfectly fine
it gets the data.
and if it is a combobox uses setCellWidget, and for normal text uses setItem:

```
        output = LoadData(sql)

        if output == []:
            return False
        
        for row in output:

            row_pos = self.table.rowCount()

            self.table.insertRow(row_pos)

            for i, column in enumerate(row, 0):

                normal_widget_item = True

                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(column))
                
                # The 12 col is always a combobox
                if i == 12:

                    item = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

                    item.addItems(self.all_messager_types)

                    item.setCurrentIndex(self.all_messager_types.index(column))

                    normal_widget_item = False
                

                if i == 15:

                    flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags()
                    flags != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
                    item.setFlags(flags)
                

                if normal_widget_item:
                    self.table.setItem(row_pos, i, item)

                else:
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row_pos,i,item)
        
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

but when I try to use it in a different thread it creates new windows for every widget.
my thread class:

```
class load_table_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,target,sql=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.sql = sql
        self.target = target
    def run(self):
        output = LoadData(self.sql)
        if output == []:
            return False
        
        for row in output:
            row_pos = self.target.table.rowCount()
            self.target.table.insertRow(row_pos)
            
            for i, column in enumerate(row, 0):
                normal_widget_item = True
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(column))
                
                if i == 12:
                    item = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    item.addItems(self.target.all_messager_types)
                    item.setCurrentIndex(self.target.all_messager_types.index(column))
                    normal_widget_item = False
                
                if i == 15:
                    flags = QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags()
                    flags != QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
                    item.setFlags(flags)

                if normal_widget_item:
                    self.target.table.setItem(row_pos, i, item)
                else:
                    self.target.table.setCellWidget(row_pos,i,item)
        
        self.target.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

and this is the way I call it:

```
th = load_table_thread(self,sql)
th.start()
```

there is not errors in runtime but the program creates new windows for every combo box ( ignore the text, just look how many windows are open for the combobox ):

See the issue image

[image]

I used the pyqt threading system too but the same problem happens.

Comment: QWidgets are not thread safe. You should never modify or create widgets from other threads than the main thread. You can fetch the data from the data base in a separate QThread but building the table itself should be done in the main thread.

Comment: It worked thanks. Although it's not as fast.